# all elements in the app are pixelated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uibutton

screenshot below has been taken from 3.5inch simulator

these are bunch of UIButton, and the border created programmatically like:

```
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width / 2;
```

[image]

i don't know, but now all Fonts and UIButtons in the app get pixelated. mostly everything got pixelated.

I checked every setting in Xcode.

I tried to clean the project, then cleaned DerivedData folder.

I tried building the app in another machine.

I tried the app on real device. same problem.

nothing worked out yet.

Comment: have you tried it on real device? I'm working on real project now with rounded buttons and haven't met this problem

Comment: Yep I've tried it on real device, same problem. it's so weird!!

Comment: Are you using any images?

Comment: no, in the screenshot it's just simple UIButtons.

Comment: You're saying that adding the line `btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width / 2;` causes other in the app to become pixellated, and removing that fixes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get pixellation on retina devices is rasterizing layers without setting the right `rasterizationScale`.

```
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
```

Without the second line, stuff will look fine for non-retina devices but it'll look awful on retina devices.

...hard to say if that's the problem you're seeing without more of the code, but it's a common enough bug that it merits posting.

Whether or not you should actually be rasterizing is a separate question...there are performance tradeoffs of which to be aware.

Comment: thnx very much @Ian, I was giving all my UIViewControllers shadow effect, and I put self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; to boost the performance, now when I removed this line ... every thing worked just fine.

Comment: @homam A better way to improve performance of shadow rendering is to use the `layer.shadowPath` property. It's still expensive if you have a high radius, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: yep, i notice a bad performance. I've tried
`vc.view.layer.shadowColor           = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        vc.view.layer.shadowRadius          = 10;
        vc.view.layer.shadowOpacity         = .25;
        vc.view.layer.shouldRasterize       = YES;
        vc.view.layer.rasterizationScale    = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
        self.view.layer.shadowPath          = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.frame].CGPath;`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the resulting frame isn't aligned on an even integer. i.e. Moving/changing width  is causing the frame to be something like (100.5, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0). When you are drawing on a half-pixel boundary, some of the drawing routines are going to make things look blurry to try and make it appear in the correct place. I would print out the frame after the animation and check:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(yourButton.frame));
```

If you see any non-integer values, use one of the `floor()` functions to modify the resulting frame in order to snap it to a boundary.

I had same problem with my UILabel(when i changed frame),

Before using `floor()` method:

[image]

And after:

[image]